# Como hago que me cargue datos por defecto en mat-select?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

[image: Ese es el fomulario la idea que me aparezca la semana y año maximo al inicio de la carga]

ahi esta el codigo del componente y del html , el mercado me carga por defecto pero la semana y año no se como cargan ya que la lógica es distinta.la idea que me aparezca la semana y año máximo al inicio de la carga.
con lo que tengo me carga la semana al seleccionar un año pero la idea es que en el inicio de la carga me salga los maximos

```
 <!-- Periodo -->
                <h4>Periodo de Consulta: Hasta la semana</h4>
                <!-- Semanal -->
                <!-- <div fxLayout="column" *ngIf="(parametros.tipoSerie == tiposSerie['SEMANAL']['id'])"> -->
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="{{anchoEntreCombobox.MD}}">
                        <mat-form-field [style.width]="anchoCombobox.FULL">
                            <mat-select placeholder="Hasta Semana" [(ngModel)]="parametros.semanaTermino"  name="week">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of listadoSemanaTemporada" [value]="item[0]">{{ item[0]}}</mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <mat-form-field [style.width]="anchoCombobox.FULL">
                            <mat-select placeholder="Del Año:" [(ngModel)]="annioSeleccionado" (ngModelChange)="cargarTemporada()" name="yearTermino">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let annio of listadoAnniosTemporadas" [value]="annio[1]">{{ annio[1] }}</mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
              
                <!-- Mercado -->
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="{{anchoEntreCombobox.MD}}">
                    <div fxFlex class="bottom-margin">
                        <mat-form-field [style.width]="anchoCombobox.FULL">
                            <mat-select placeholder="Mercado" [(ngModel)]="parametros.mercado" name="market" [disabled]="parametros.todoMercado">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let mercado of listadoMercados" [value]="mercado.empCod">{{ mercado.empDes }}</mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

[Ese es el json que me devuelve](https://pastebin.com/72xMACZi)

[la clase componente](https://pastebin.com/qHR3ZiFb)

Comment: ya intentaste llenar los datos en el método onInit?

Comment: no.eso nunca lo intentado. como deberían llenarse los datos desde ahi?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo los valores que cargas en tus mat-option son del tipo array [50,1999] y el valor de tu mat-select es un number 49.
De esa manera nunca van a coincidir y por ende no se van a seleccionar automáticamente.

Fíjate en el valor del [(ngModel)]="" de tu mat-select, este debe coincidir con algún valor de las mat-option cargadas en tu select con [value]="" para que se queden seleccionas por defecto.

Una solución para tu problema parece ser tan simple como
cambiar la carga de tu mat-option de eso.

```
item[0]
```

Por esto.

```
item[0][0]
```

De esta forma tus mat-options tendrían un valores del tipo number 50 en lugar de array [50,1999].

Saludos

Comment: Lo deje como me dijiste , pero no funciona `<mat-select placeholder="Hasta Semana" [(ngModel)]="parametros.semanaTermino" name="week">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of listadoSemanaTemporada" [value]="item[0][0]">{{ item[0][0]}}</mat-option>
                                </mat-select>`

Comment: ¿Comprobaste que los datos coincidan?. Que dato tienes en semana parametros.semanaTermino y cúal tienes en listadoSemanaTemporada.

En modo de debug pon encima de tu select {{ listadoSemanaTemporada | json }} y {{ listadoSemanaTemporada | json }} para que puedas ver los datos que tienes cargados en tiempo real.

Comment: [https://imgur.com/a/FMdytHe](https://imgur.com/a/FMdytHe) Mira eso me esta devoliendo en la carga inicial ........... Igual llevo muy poco con angular y hay conceptos que no manejo bien . Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Estoy probando y al seleccionar un año me carga automáticamente la semana 24 , pero en la carga inicial esta vacío el json , al seleccionar el año se completa el campo semana

Comment: ¿Que datos contiene tu "listadoSemanaTemporada" ?.

Puede que no le estés cargando los datos y tengas que hacerlo.

Comment: El listadoSemanaTemporada se llena al seleccionar un año (ngModelChange)="cargarTemporada(), fue la forma que encontré de cargar las semanas dependiendo del año , pero haciendo eso me complica hacer la carga inicial. hice un console.log(this.listadoSemanaTemporada) y cuando seleciono el año se llena la semana

Comment: Creo que se debería cargar la temporada(año) por defecto, así la semana cambiaría su valor a la vez . Creo...